# google dictionary api returns non utf-8 characters, how to deal with this?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Google api returns these:

```
 after the emwar/em, they emigrated to America

she was bat emwar/em with/b her parents
```

Where em - is `<em>`
And b/b - is `<strong>`

Is there a good-reliable way to transform these into real html tags?

API I'm using is this: http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q=love&sl=en&tl=en

inside response I've

```
\x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e
```

http headers:

```
Request URL:
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
icl_v=927073665.1535459377395.1384764456.2; icl_b=8; __utma=196281136.2083409047.1383570651.1384866168.1384869814.74; __utmc=196281136; __utmz=196281136.1383570651.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1766
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 19 Nov 2013 18:16:06 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.26 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.26
```

Comment: You're doing *something* wrong. That data is useless, you can't go back to sane `<em>` tags. How can you tell how to fix a string like `the word embargo is embad for business/em`? or simply `babby/b`?

Comment: @meagar take a look yourself: http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q=love&sl=en&tl=en

Comment: @RedBalloon Err, there *are* UTF16 characters in there. You've misrepresented your data. `A personified figure of \x3cem\x3elove\x3c/em\x3e`.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's *not* "super easy". It's not even possible, unless you add some restrictions. What about `emem/em`? Is that supposed to be `em<em></em>` or `<em>em</em>`? That's my point: If I have a string like `embark on eman embedded journey/em`, how can you possibly tell which `em` matches the `/em`?

Comment: @hek2mgl Then tell me how you would do it, for any of my examples. Turn `embark on eman embedded journey/em` into `<em></em>` for me with a regular expression.

Comment: @meagar instead of arguing, maybe give me a hint :), what should I do with utf-16 chars?

Comment: @hek2mgl Your output is wrong. The source string was `embark on <em>an embedded journey</em>`.

Comment: @hek2mgl how do I deal with utf-16 chars?

Comment: @RedBalloon Can you show the HTTP response headers you got?

Comment: @meagar ? how should it? `\x3cbob` is perfect ascii (without having more info) `JSON.parse` is javascript

Comment: @meagar I do run it through json_decod in php, and this is where these characters disappear, hence my error in OP.

Comment: @RedBalloon Try to enforce, lets say utf-8, using the request headers

Comment: @RedBalloon send `Accept-Charset: utf-8` with the request headers. If you are a lucky guy google will respect it

Comment: @hek2mgl you mean in curl? or in html?

Comment: With curl if you are using it..

Comment: @hek2mgl nope, didn't help...

Comment: Yeah, I see............

Comment: @hek2mgl actually, I just noticed, I run this code through: $output = preg_replace("/\\\x[0-9a-f]{2}/", "", $output); this effectively removes utf-16 chars.

Comment: @RedBalloon Have given an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found solution myself...

```
$from = array("\\x3e", "\\x3c");
        $to = array(">", "<");
        $output = str_replace($from, $to, $output);
```